# List of table categories in select list / dropdown list

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on a new project and decided to use .net core 3.0. I am completely new to this framework and I am stuck on task where I would like to change my template by adding select list that will contains model's data grouped by category.

At the moment I have done tutorial where each category can be sort by  using sortOrder parameter in a table - from  tutorial that is available at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-3.0.  What I am trying to do is to add separate dropdown list ad sort records based on table headers.
[image]

at the moment my view looks like

```
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <a asp-action="Index" asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["NameSortParm"]">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)</a>
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstMidName)
        </th>
        <th>
            <a asp-action="Index" asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["DateSortParm"]">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EnrollmentDate)</a>
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

and my controller has following action method ...

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string sortOrder)
    {
        ViewData["NameSortParm"] = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
        ViewData["DateSortParm"] = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";
        var students = from s in _context.StudentsModel
                       select s;


        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "name_desc":
                students = students.OrderByDescending(s => s.LastName);
                break;
            case "Date":
                students = students.OrderBy(s => s.EnrollmentDate);
                break;
            case "date_desc":
                students = students.OrderByDescending(s => s.EnrollmentDate);
                break;
            default:
                students = students.OrderBy(s => s.LastName);
                break;
        }
        return View(await students.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync());

        //return View(await _context.Students.ToListAsync());
    }
```

I have looked on a number of websites but did not found solution so I will be very grateful if someone could help me to achieve desirable result.

Comment: Has anyone clue how this can be achieved? I saw some examples using JQuery but I was wonder if there another way to do it.